# Can I 'import' this value into a XML structure and parse it? C#

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint server and I am playing around with it programmatically. One of the applications that I am playing with is [Microsoft's Call Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4EAB254B-F775-476D-83A7-A232DD3A21F4&displaylang=en). I queried the list of customers:

```
if (cList.Title.ToLower().Equals("service requests"))
{
    textBox1.Text += "> Service Requests" + Environment.NewLine;
    foreach (SPListItem item in cList.Items)
    {
        textBox1.Text += string.Format(">> {0}{1}", item.Title, Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

One of the properties in `item` is XML. Here is value of one:

```
<z:row
  xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' ows_ID='1' ows_ContentTypeId='0x0106006324F8B638865542BE98AD18210EB6F4'
  ows_ContentType='Contact' ows_Title='Mouse' ows_Modified='2009-08-12 14:53:50' ows_Created='2009-08-12 14:53:50'
  ows_Author='1073741823;#System Account' ows_Editor='1073741823;#System Account'
  ows_owshiddenversion='1' ows_WorkflowVersion='1' ows__UIVersion='512' ows__UIVersionString='1.0'
  ows_Attachments='0' ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows_LinkTitleNoMenu='Mouse' ows_LinkTitle='Mouse'
  ows_SelectTitle='1' ows_Order='100.000000000000' ows_GUID='{37A91B6B-B645-446A-8E8D-DA8250635DE1}'
  ows_FileRef='1;#Lists/customersList/1_.000' ows_FileDirRef='1;#Lists/customersList'
  ows_Last_x0020_Modified='1;#2009-08-12 14:53:50' ows_Created_x0020_Date='1;#2009-08-12 14:53:50'
  ows_FSObjType='1;#0' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_FileLeafRef='1;#1_.000'
  ows_UniqueId='1;#{28A223E0-100D-49A6-99DA-7947CFC38B18}' ows_ProgId='1;#'
  ows_ScopeId='1;#{79BF21FE-0B9A-43B1-9077-C071B61F5588}' ows__EditMenuTableStart='1_.000'
  ows__EditMenuTableEnd='1' ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu='1_.000' ows_LinkFilename='1_.000'
  ows_ServerUrl='/Lists/customersList/1_.000' ows_EncodedAbsUrl='http://spvm:3333/Lists/customersList/1_.000'
  ows_BaseName='1_' ows_MetaInfo='1;#' ows__Level='1' ows__IsCurrentVersion='1' ows_FirstName='Mickey'
  ows_FullName='Mickey Mouse' ows_Comments='&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;' ows_ServerRedirected='0'
/>
```

Can I create an XMLnode or some other sort of XML object so that I can easily parse it and pull certain values (these certainties are unknowns right now, since I am just testing right now)?

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the XML is valid you could use XmlDocument.LoadXMl like so:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(validxmlstring);
```

Comment: Hrm, I must have overlooked that one. I was trying to use XPath but was unsuccessful. Probably, like I mentioned, due to my lack of experience with XML parsing in .NET. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this and it should work fine (although I would use the XML document approach [Colin mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268500/can-i-import-this-value-into-a-xml-structure-and-parse-it-c/1270475#1270475), or even better LINQ). You may also find the LINQ extensions in [SharePoint Extensions Lib](http://spexlib.codeplex.com/) useful.

However, I'm wondering why you would approach it this way instead of using the [SPListItem.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464204.aspx) property? It's much simpler to use and very clear. For example:

```
var title = listItem["Title"];       // Returns title of item
var desc = listItem["Description"];  // Returns value of description field
```

The only trap is the unusual case of a list that contains a field with an internal name equal to another field's display name. This will always return the value of the field with the internal name first.

Just curious if you have a requirement to go the XML route.

Comment: No, I do not necessarily have to use XML for this. I just thought it would be the easiest way to consume the raw data.

Comment: Oh, I just remembered why the XML: Inside of the list I get from the server the data that I want to consume is inside of the list's XML property. There are some bits of info that I could pull directly from the list, but most is inside that XML field.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code that seems to work ok. Since my XML/C# knowledge is limited I would imagine there is a simpler way:

```
public void DoParse(string value, string elementname)
{
    var split = value.Split((char)39);

    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.CreateElement(elementname);
    xDoc.AppendChild(xRoot);

    for (var i = 0; i < split.Length - 1; i += 2)
    {
        var attribName = split[i].Replace("=", "").Trim();
        var xAttrib = xDoc.CreateAttribute(attribName);
        xAttrib.Value = split[i + 1];
        xRoot.Attributes.Append(xAttrib);
    }
    xDoc.Save(string.Format("c:\\xmlout_{0}.xml", elementname));
}
```

Gives me:

> `<Customer xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_ID="1" ows_ContentTypeId="0x0106006324F8B638865542BE98AD18210EB6F4" ows_ContentType="Contact" ows_Title="Mouse" ows_Modified="2009-08-12 14:53:50" ows_Created="2009-08-12 14:53:50" ows_Author="1073741823;#System Account" ows_Editor="1073741823;#System Account" ows_owshiddenversion="1" ows_WorkflowVersion="1" ows__UIVersion="512" ows__UIVersionString="1.0" ows_Attachments="0" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="Mouse" ows_LinkTitle="Mouse" ows_SelectTitle="1" ows_Order="100.000000000000" ows_GUID="{37A91B6B-B645-446A-8E8D-DA8250635DE1}" ows_FileRef="1;#Lists/customersList/1_.000" ows_FileDirRef="1;#Lists/customersList" ows_Last_x0020_Modified="1;#2009-08-12 14:53:50" ows_Created_x0020_Date="1;#2009-08-12 14:53:50" ows_FSObjType="1;#0" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileLeafRef="1;#1_.000" ows_UniqueId="1;#{28A223E0-100D-49A6-99DA-7947CFC38B18}" ows_ProgId="1;#" ows_ScopeId="1;#{79BF21FE-0B9A-43B1-9077-C071B61F5588}" ows__EditMenuTableStart="1_.000" ows__EditMenuTableEnd="1" ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu="1_.000" ows_LinkFilename="1_.000" ows_ServerUrl="/Lists/customersList/1_.000" ows_EncodedAbsUrl="http://spvm:3333/Lists/customersList/1_.000" ows_BaseName="1_" ows_MetaInfo="1;#" ows__Level="1" ows__IsCurrentVersion="1" ows_FirstName="Mickey" ows_FullName="Mickey Mouse" ows_Comments="&amp;lt;div&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;" ows_ServerRedirected="0" />`

Anyone have some input? Thanks.

Comment: You're effectively writing your own XML parser here, except that you're not doing it right (as XML can get much more complicated - consider character entities, comments etc). Just don't do it - use the existing parsers as suggested in other replies.

Comment: Thank you pavel, I will try those out.